# How to generate WSQ file from fingerprint template in Android?

Tags: android, fingerprint

I want to generate/convert WSQ file from fingerprint template. I can get byte array and bitmap from the template, but my requirement is to get WSQ file.

Can i generate WSQ file for free or it is paid only? Can you suggest ways on how to get WSQ file? I have tried looking at [this](https://github.com/mhshams/jnbis) but it gives me reverse output and i couldn't find what i want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have a look at these links, to convert fingerprint raw image to WSQ

- http://jmrtd.org/index.shtml
- https://github.com/E3V3A/JMRTD/tree/master/wsq_imageio

*** EDIT1 ***

And theses classes:

- https://github.com/E3V3A/JMRTD/blob/master/wsq_imageio/src/org/jnbis/WSQEncoder.java
- https://github.com/E3V3A/JMRTD/blob/master/wsq_imageio/src/org/jnbis/test/WSQTest.java

You'll find code to encode from bitmap to WSQ:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ...;
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(WSQ_FILE_OUT);
WSQEncoder.encode(outputStream, bitmap, bitrate, commentText);
outputStream.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, i have already gone through these links.

Comment: I have used Morpho SDk for getting fingerprint. From that i get template of fingerprint and from that i get normal bitmap of fingerprint image.

Comment: Thanks again. I will try this out.

Comment: Note: that's not Android's `com.android.graphics.Bitmap` class, but `org.jnbis.Bitmap`. If your `byte[]` holds 8-bit gray-scale values it should be easy enough to construct one of these.

Comment: I got successful in generating the required output from this method. Thank you.

Comment: can anybody know how to get template(base64) from *.wsq file? I have lots of physical stored *.wsq biometrictdata file. I have to get fingerprint template from secugen fingerprint scanner and match with that *.wsq file. so before authenticate i have to convert *.wsq file to fingerprint template.

Comment: I am trying exactly the same, exporting from Morpho SDK bitmap to wsq format and i can not compile the library because the javax.imageio dependencies. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: @PriyankaAlachiya can you help me out as how did you achieve this? I have a fingerprint template in bytes as to how am I suppose to convert it to WSQ?

Comment: HI @muhammadYousuf do you still need my help?

Comment: Yes your help will be much appreciated. I am able to get the fingerprint and show it as a bitmap now I want the WSQ data of that bitmap/fingerprint to send it to my server. So, do I need to create a WSQ file, read that file and then send that data to server or can I send it directly?
Although I used another approach which is a very long, it seems like you achieved it easily plus a short and clean approach is what I am looking for :P.

Comment: @LaurenTy Am facing the same challenge here as the original question. Am just wondering which of the jnbis version has this code 'WSQEncoder.encode(outputStream, bitmap, bitrate, commentText);' sample because I don't seem to find it even after I add the dependency.

Comment: @MuhammadYousuf Did you manage this? Am in a similar situation and I would appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

**Generally**
, a Template is metadata extracted from the image for comparison against another template. But there is no way to get the image from the template.

(Is only a little bit like hashing in that regard, you can generate a hash from the image, but not the image from the hash.)

**However,** there seems to be research stating that a fingerprint image could be used to do so, but IMHO it is research for now. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221145072_Can_Fingerprints_be_Reconstructed_from_ISO_Templates

Then if we start from the general understanding, the image is the one that needs to be stored, and the template taken from it for fingerprint comparison.
https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-0-387-73003-5_51