# How to generate WSQ file from fingerprint template in Android

Tags: android, file, fingerprint, biometrics, image-scanner

@ https://stackoverflow.com/users/4439179/priyanka-alachiya

"I got successful in generating the required output from this method. Thank you"

[How to generate WSQ file from fingerprint template in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56426809/how-to-generate-wsq-file-from-fingerprint-template-in-android)

Kindly assist with how you generated the wsq file from the fingerprint bitmap.

Regards

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your question is wrongly written.

Templates are generated based on the source sample images, the templates are the binary and computer friendly representation of the biometric characteristics of that sample.

The template is a reduced set of information, from which you can't get back the original image.

Think about it as converting a CD song into an MP3 song; you get a reduced representation from the original, but you cannot get back the same song with same quality (or finger image) from the reduced source.

Image -> Template: OK, it is possible
Template -> Image: Not possible